# How to solve SSL error fetching audio path

Tags: ssl, fetch, mp3

Ive been trying to use an mp3 file from a lyrics API - https://lyrics.ovh in a HTML audio element. But Ive been getting the following cors error (it doesnt happen locally, but when i deploy to gitpages it occurs).

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This is how Ive been trying to solve it:

I have tried one of the solutions as mentioned here: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141), to deploy my own proxy to Heroku. It works for one url I need, but for the one containing the mp3 path it doesnt.
The response returns status:200, but I get error :unexpected token in JSON.

console error:

> GET [http://127.0.0.1:5500/[object%20Promise]](http://127.0.0.1:5500/%5Bobject%20Promise%5D) 404 (Not Found)
> script.js:89 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in
> JSON at position 0

```
const cors = https://my-proxy.herokuapp.com


// get Mp3 
 async function getMP3(url) {
    const res = await fetch(`${cors}/${url}`, {
    headers: {
              "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
              Accept: "audio/mpeg",
            },
    });
    const data = await res.json();   // this line causes the error
 }
```

// example of url: (proxy url + path to mp3)

```
https://my-proxy.herokuapp.com/http://cdn-preview-e.deezer.com/stream/c-e6b5f2295c3af5280cc00b3bf842ff57-9.mp3
```

// audio element

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="${getMP3(url)}" type="audio/mpeg">       
</audio>
```

Comment: Has this been resolved? If so, and the answer was helpful to you, please mark it as "Accepted". Otherwise, if you'd like some more clarification, just say so.

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` is an HTTPS error, not a CORS error. It means that the SSL certificate of the domain you're attempting to connect to is invalid.

More specifically, `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` means it's invalid because the SSL certificate is registered to a different domain(Or subdomain) than the domain you're attempting to connect to.

Comment: @user6086008 If you give us the exact URL of the API, we can give you more information about the error. But you can check yourself simply by putting the URL of the API into your chrome address bar, opening up Chrome's Dev tools, and going to the "Security" tab.

Comment: The error on Security tab says  `This page is not secure. Resources - mixed content`.

Sample project can be found here: 
**https://trinajoy.github.io/lyrics-search** - search for a song and press 'lyrics' - and see the audio element wont play, and console error about `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Sample url for audio element is:
http://cdn-preview-e.deezer.com/stream/c-e6b5f2295c3af5280cc00b3bf842ff57-9.mp3

Comment: @user6086008 As you can see when connecting to that sample URL in chrome using HTTPS, you get an error. The error says the HTTPS certificate is only valid for `a248.e.akamai.net`. You'll need to fix your HTTPS on the server `cdn-preview-e.deezer.com`, or connect using that domain name instead.

Comment: @user6086008 Can you contact your hosting provider and get them to fix it? Or are you managing it?

Comment: By the way, the error I'm referring to is on this link: https://cdn-preview-e.deezer.com/stream/c-e6b5f2295c3af5280cc00b3bf842ff57-9.mp3

Comment: (Of course, you can *also* change "HTTPS" to "HTTP" for all your URLS, and that should fix the problem too...... But I don't know if that's the solution you want.)

Comment: Im just deploying this project to github pages.

Comment: add chrome extension 'Allow CORS' seemed to fix the issue